# Iotivity client doesn't discover resources after some time

Tags: embedded-linux, iotivity

I'm running an IoTivity client that rediscovers available resources every 20 seconds. At the start it works fine. However, after around 2 and a half minutes the client doesn't discover the resource anymore. When I restart the client it still doesn't find it but when I restart the server the client rediscover it but for 2:30 min. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
I'm using IoTivity 1.2.1 and I'm running the server and the client on different embedded devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the "classic" iotivity, not only is 1.2.1 rather old (last release was 1.4), but that project has largely been abandoned except for historical interest, in favor of iotivity-lite.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried IoTivity lite and still have the same issue.

Comment: I've been away from iovitity projects for some time now so can't help much. If the problem followed you to a different implementation, I'd guess at some local issue.  OCF protocols depend (or at least used to) rather heavily on multicast UDP for discovery, is there a chance there's some blocking or throttling on the network - router, access point, etc? Multicast sometimes isn't fully enabled. Your server-restart experiment suggests it's not that though.